# Problem with looping through EntitySubscription

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

Im passing an array of Ids from my JS into currentUserId,

JS

```
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:actionFunction action="{! removeFollower }" name="processId" oncomplete="refresh()">
            <apex:param assignTo="{! currentUserId }" name="userId" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
```

EXTENSION

```
   public String[] currentUserId { get; set; }
```

I want to then loop through EntitySubscription and delete each of them. This method works for single Ids, but I need to edit it to accept multiple Ids.

```
    public PageReference removeFollower() {         
    try {

        for(Integer i = 0; i<currentUserId.length; i++){
                EntitySubscription subscription = [SELECT parentId FROM 
                                                   EntitySubscription 
                                                   WHERE subscriberId = :currentUserId[i]
                                                   AND parentId = :id];
                Delete subscription; 
           }       
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            system.debug('Error: ' + ex);
        }
        return null;   
    }
```

At the moment, I'm getting this error.

```
Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<String>
```

Would anyone have any suggestions or advice?

Comment: You're trying too hard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void removeFollower() {         
    Database.DeleteResult[] results = Database.delete([SELECT Id FROM EntitySubscription WHERE SubscriberId IN :currentUserId AND ParentId = :Id LIMIT 500], false);
    // process results here
}
```

Comment: Delete results; Is throwing up an error,

Comment: What error? And for admin or non-admin?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's admin or non-admin, sorry Error: Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: LIST<Database.DeleteResult> .

Comment: sorry... I copied it wrong. My heads pretty melted at the moment.

Comment: How are you passing in the values? Can you share that code, too?

Comment: Using the <apex:actionFunction /> at the top of the page. It calls the 'processId' function in my JS which processes a list of checkboxes. Depending on which checkboxes are ticked, a list of user Ids are are stored in an array and passed into the 'currentUserId' String[].

Comment: That's interesting, because I can't seem to pass the array into the function directly. I get an error about failing to cast a String to a String[]. If you would kindly post the `processId` function, it'd help me help you (plus, apparently, I'll learn something new).